# start program in php

Tags: php, startup

I want to have a site in PHP that is able to start and stop a program on my local machine. Until now, I was only able to shutdown the program, but i can't get it to start. It has to work on a extern machine (anywhere else then my network) as well.
The site is hosted on Wamp server

My code is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['shutdown'])) {
  $cmd = "taskkill /f /im euroscopefsdserver.exe /t";
  shell_exec($cmd);
}
if (isset($_POST['start'])) {
  shell_exec("E:\\Programma's\Euroscope\euroscopefsdserver");
}
if (isset($_POST['restart'])) {
  $cmd = "taskkill /f /im euroscopefsdserver.exe /t";
  $cmd2 = "E:\Programma's\Euroscope\EuroScopeFsdServer";
  shell_exec($cmd);
  shell_exec($cmd2);
}
 ?>


 <form action="index.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
   <input type="submit" name="shutdown" value="Shutdown">
   <input type="submit" name="restart" value="Restart">
 </form>
```

Comment: Please do not take security issues lightly. `E:` looks odd, `Programma's` downright erroneous.

Comment: What do you mean? This is just my extra 1TB HDD drive and the folder where I install my program's on it, because my C: drive is only 250GB SSD

Comment: `E:` looks "absolute" even when *not* followed by `\\xyz`. You mention `site is hosted on WAMP server`, but not *PHP code will never, ever be executed but on **one** client with* euroscopefsdserver *installed in that exact path*. Is the single apostrophe correct? What will happen to the backslashes in "the path string literal"? (Test output?)

Answer (score 0):

To launch a program on the computer which runs the webserver:

```
 <?php
    exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\foo.php"');
 ?>
```

or

```
 <?php
    $file= shell_exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe");
    echo $file."</br>";
 ?>
```

Comment: No, it won't do anything, the page is just loading the whole time... The code I have inserted is: 
 exec('"E:\Programma\'s\Euroscope\EuroScopeFsdServer.exe" "E:\Programma\'s\wamp64\www\fsdserverprogram\index.php"');

Comment: i cant see any executable in the path you gave

Comment: Weird, if I try it with Internet Explorer on my C: drive it does not keep loading but it won't start either. When i try the program i want it just keep loading...